# Missing check square (JCheckBoxMenuItem) while using Nimbus java look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jcheckbox, nimbus

I changed to Nimbus look and feel, as it is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html).

It works fine except for JCheckBoxMenuItems, where the check squares disappeared. The selection color is incorrect too.

**This is the code of the popupmenu with the JCheckBoxMenuItems:**

```
public class FilterByNodeUI 
{
    private JPopupMenu filterMenu;
    private PopupMenuButton menu;
    private JMenu eventLogFilters, commandFilters;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem[] commandsPeriodicalItems, commandsPeriodicalAllPortsItems;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem alarm, connection, standard;
    private String id;

public FilterByNodeUI(Node node)
{
    this.id = node.getIp();

    filterMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    eventLogFilter();

    int cpNbr = node.getCommands().getCommandsPeriodical().size();
    int cpapNbr = node.getCommands().getCommandsPeriodicalAllPorts().size();
    commandsPeriodicalItems = new JCheckBoxMenuItem[cpNbr];
    commandsPeriodicalAllPortsItems = new JCheckBoxMenuItem[cpapNbr];

    commandFilters = new JMenu("Commands");

    for(int i = 0; i < cpNbr; i++)
    {
        commandsPeriodicalItems[i] = menuItemFactory(node.getCommands().getCommandsPeriodical().get(i).getCommand());
        commandFilters.add(commandsPeriodicalItems[i]);
    }

    commandFilters.addSeparator();

    for(int i = 0; i < cpapNbr; i++)
    {
        commandsPeriodicalAllPortsItems[i] = menuItemFactory(node.getCommands().getCommandsPeriodicalAllPorts().get(i).getCommand());
        commandFilters.add(commandsPeriodicalAllPortsItems[i]);
    }

    filterMenu.add(eventLogFilters);
    filterMenu.add(commandFilters);

    menu = new PopupMenuButton(node.getDispName(), filterMenu);


    commandFilterListeners(commandsPeriodicalItems, node, true);
    commandFilterListeners(commandsPeriodicalAllPortsItems, node, false);   
}

private void eventLogFilter()
{
    alarm = menuItemFactory("Alarm messages");
    standard = menuItemFactory("Standard messages");
    connection = menuItemFactory("Connection messages");

    eventLogFilters = new JMenu("Event Log Messages");
    eventLogFilters.add(alarm);
    eventLogFilters.add(connection);
    eventLogFilters.add(standard);
}

private JCheckBoxMenuItem menuItemFactory(String name)
{
    JCheckBoxMenuItem tmp;
    tmp = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(name);
    tmp.setSelected(true);
    tmp.setUI(new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI());  // I set a new UI here
    return tmp;
}
}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: missing check square]

It seems to me that the new look and feel did not apply for the JCheckBoxMenuitems or the JMenu.

The cause of the problem is that I set a new UI for hte JCheckBoxMenuItems because I do not want to close the popup menu when the user checks/unchecks an item.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI extends BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI 
{
   @Override
   protected void doClick(MenuSelectionManager msm) 
   {
       menuItem.doClick(0);
   }

   public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c)
   {
       return new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI();
   }
}
```

Is there a way to keep this unclosing feature beside the nimbus look and feel?

Comment: quite funny, maybe I'm blind,  is there... nothing from code showing something about JMenu and JCheckjBoxMenuItem

Comment: With the default look and feel it works correctly so I thought that part of the code is not necessary. I have to override somehow the nimbus's properties for JCheckBoxMenuItem. But I can edit my question and insert that code snippet if you require.

Comment: As mKorbel pointed out, you haven't shown us the whole code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. For instance, you haven't shown how or where `MainFrame` or `menu` were instantiated and initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not an answer [code by aterai from OTN](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1353120?start=0&tstart=0)

[image] [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// JDK 1.6
//import com.sun.java.swing.*;
//import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.*;
//__________________________________________
// JDK 1.7
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.*;

class NimbusCheckIconTest {

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JCheckBoxMenuItem cbmi = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("checkIcon test");
        UIDefaults d = new UIDefaults();
        d.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[Enabled].checkIconPainter",
                new MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter(
                MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter.CHECKICON_ENABLED));
        d.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[MouseOver].checkIconPainter",
                new MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter(
                MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter.CHECKICON_MOUSEOVER));
        d.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[Enabled+Selected].checkIconPainter",
                new MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter(
                MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter.CHECKICON_ENABLED_SELECTED));
        d.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[MouseOver+Selected].checkIconPainter",
                new MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter(
                MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter.CHECKICON_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER));
        cbmi.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
        cbmi.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("default"));
        menu.add(cbmi);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    public Container createContentPane() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));
        return contentPane;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        NimbusCheckIconTest demo = new NimbusCheckIconTest();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
        f.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
        f.setSize(320, 240);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
//copy: CheckBoxMenuItemPainter.java
class MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter extends AbstractRegionPainter {

    static final int CHECKICON_ENABLED_SELECTED = 6;
    static final int CHECKICON_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER = 7;
    static final int CHECKICON_ENABLED = 8;
    static final int CHECKICON_MOUSEOVER = 9;
    private int state;
    private PaintContext ctx;

    public MyCheckBoxMenuItemPainter(int state) {
        super();
        this.state = state;
        this.ctx = new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(
                new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), new Dimension(9, 10), false, null, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPaint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c,
            int width, int height, Object[] eckey) {
        switch (state) {
            case CHECKICON_ENABLED:
                paintcheckIconEnabled(g);
                break;
            case CHECKICON_MOUSEOVER:
                paintcheckIconMouseOver(g);
                break;
            case CHECKICON_ENABLED_SELECTED:
                paintcheckIconEnabledAndSelected(g);
                break;
            case CHECKICON_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER:
                paintcheckIconSelectedAndMouseOver(g);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected PaintContext getPaintContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    private void paintcheckIconEnabled(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }

    private void paintcheckIconMouseOver(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(Color.PINK);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }

    private void paintcheckIconEnabledAndSelected(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }

    private void paintcheckIconSelectedAndMouseOver(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aterai please isn't easier to use ButtonModel as test this state in doPaint

Comment: @mKorbel I quite agree, `java.swing.Painter#doPaint()` + `ButtonModel` would be much easier :)