# There is no square for JCheckBoxMenuItem in Nimbus?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I just found there is no square for the `JCheckBoxMenuItem` in Nimbus.

If you disable the use of Nimbus, the square will show up. If you switch to Nimbus, the square will not show up.

Is it by design?

There is an example that shows the square is missing: [Missing check square (JCheckBoxMenuItem) while using Nimbus java look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404240/missing-check-square-jcheckboxmenuitem-while-using-nimbus-java-look-and-feel)

Comment: Link does not show up.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: By design. If you want a square, use a different L&F.